What kind of sequence are range and bytearray?
In the "Fluent Python" book by Luciano Ramalho (2nd ed.) he defines the concepts of container sequences and flat sequences:

A container sequence holds references to the objects it contains, which may be of any type, while a flat sequence stores the value of its contents in its own memory space, not as distinct Python objects.

Can we say that objects of type range and bytearray are flat sequences (I think that these objects can't contain references but not sure)?
And is there a simple way to test whether a sequence is flat or not?

I just found this post that gives a quote from the 1st edition of the "Fluent Python" book (I personally only have the 2nd edition):

Flat sequences: str, bytes, bytearray, memoryview, and array.array hold items of one type.

So, it seems that bytearray is a flat sequence. In the 2nd edition (p.22) the author says only that

Flat sequences – Hold items of one simple type. Some examples: str, bytes, and array.array.
Container sequences – Can hold items of different types, including nested containers. Some examples: list, tuple, and collections.deque.


Hmmm. I don't think range stores objects at all, it creates them on demand if and when necessary.

I'm not familiar with the book, but I'm not sure what's the point of making such a distinction in the first place. The things that matter for a sequence are that they're iterable and have a known length, not whatever the layout in memory looks like.

@wim some of us still remember Python 2 where range really did create a list.  Hasn't been true for a great while now.

@wim it's a little bit more than that. For instance a set isn't a sequence. A sequence is a collection that defines an order over its elements.

I think "flat sequence" may be intended to describe things like numpy arrays. Otherwise, I can't think of python containers that store the values in their own memory.

Python has a definition for Container and for Sequence in collections.abc. Coming up with a new term "container sequence" which is anything other than the combination of both is misleading.

Technically, it's not impossible to implement (in C) a custom container that has both properties, so I don't think there's an easy and accurate way to test it.

@KlausD. I am not sure that this definition is "canonical". Because in Data model chapter the docs says that "Some objects contain references to other objects; these are called containers.". So, according to this page, container is an object that contain references to other objects. Also note that collections.abc.Sequence is not always the same thing that is desribed in this glossary entry.

If we are going to be picky, struct holds items of multiple types in a contiguous chunk of memory. Does that make them bumpy sequences?

You have it right about bytearray. It references an internal mutable memory space to hold objects of just one simple type (bytes), so it's a flat sequence, by the author's definition.
A range object is a bit more tricky though. I'd say it doesn't match either of the criteria given by the author, though it's certainly a sequence. Rather than containing any values however, it just stores the start, stop and step arguments it's constructed with, and calculates what values it should contain on the fly, as they're needed. It doesn't reference them, as Python objects or otherwise, until then. This means you can create a range of any size in constant time, since nothing but a few integers needs to be allocated.
A final note: The definitions of "flat sequence" and "container sequence" are not widely used in the Python development community. They may be useful in the context of your book to explain some differences in container behavior, but they won't be understood by Python programmers more widely. In general, the details of how a given container stores its contents are not usually something you need to care about. Leaving implementation details unspecified is often a deliberate choice by Python's design team, so that if a more efficient implementation becomes available, the code can be switched to it. This happened not long ago with Python's dictionaries, which became ordered (by insertion order) as a side effect of an implementation change. Because many of the previous implementation's details were unspecified, there was no break in backwards compatibility, since all the documented interfaces still worked the same way.


Can we say that objects of type range and bytearray are flat sequences (I think that these objects can't contain references but not sure)?

range is not a container sequence at all. It doesn't store anything except the original parameters and the current position, and generates values on the fly as needed. You can index it like a sequence, but it actually calculates the value (r[i] == r.start + i*r.step if it's less than r.stop).
Examples of flat sequences are strings, byte arrays, and numpy arrays. However, the way these are stored is an implementation detail. There's nothing technically prohibiting them from using references to objects, it would just be very inefficient, both in storage space and in the implementation of functions that use them.

You can find the length of, index and slice a range object just fine. You could call it a "virtual" sequence (since it doesn't actually contain what it purports to), but it's got all the methods a sequence is expected to have.

I am no the person who downvoted your answer but I should admit that Python docs says that "The range type represents an immutable sequence of numbers", also isinstance(range(3), collections.abc.Sequence) returns True. Finally, range(5)[2] returns 2 - indexing works...

I've changed my answer to say that it's not a container sequence @Blckknght
